# Beatles, "She's Leaving Home", Chord Question

Tags: theory, sheet-music, editions

Beatles, "She's Leaving Home", Chord Question

In the first line there's an F#m7, but when I was figuring out the chords while listening to the song, it sounds like an Amajor to me.

[image: "She's Leaving Home" first 3 measures of the verse]

F#m7 -  A C# E F#

Amajor - A C# E

(F#m is the relative minor chord of the key of Amajor. Three frets down from A. Amaj key has three sharps, C#-F#-G#. So you write down every other letter name starting at F, F-A-C-E, and you sharp the ones from the key. F#-A-C#-E.)

And in this online version of the music the E is on top in the piano line (line 2) while in my printed 'complete score' (not shown) the top note is the F#.

Is the printed score in error? If so are errors common in scores that aren't 'official'?

Answer (score 4):

Errors are hugely common — to the point of being the norm — in "unofficial" scores ("unofficial" meaning, "free, downloadable transcriptions published illegally on the net").

The E in the melody, on the word "Five" is correct.

In the first verse, I agree that the chord sounds like A major (the F#, if there, might be in the middle somewhere: i.e., an inverted F#min7 — update: see below); however, in the second verse, it's clearly F#min7. The F# is in the cello, a bit quiet, but clearly audible if you train your ear on it.

---

Update:

There are recordings on YouTube of the Beatles's takes of just the backing tracks. The one below is where I can most clearly hear the F#m7 in the first verse. It's faint, but it's there, and you can hear (or at least *feel*) it resolve to E in the next chord.

As best I can tell, the chord is in second inversion (i.e., F#min7/C#)

Comment: I agree, first inversion F#m7 on the first verse in the harp which sounds like an A6 but the low F# is there in the cello on the second verse.

Comment: @Aaron  ok, thank you. I'll listen to the second verse. In the first the high E just sounds righter.

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy That was a huge help. I can't hear it in the full recording, but I found it in (one of the takes of) the backing track alone. I'm going with second inversion. I think there's a stepwise descending lowest note, and I hear the A on top across the Bm7 and F#m7: E - Bm/D - F#m7/C#.

Comment: @RandyZeitman Glad it helped. Your vote is thanks a-plenty. Cheers.

Comment: The low F# in the cello on the second verse is enough for me to say F#m7 regardless of the inversion the harpist plays. It’s great to hear the backing tracks, who do you think wrote the string and harp arrangement, Paul or John? (I’m kidding, of course it had to be the “other George”)

Answer (score 1):

A6 contains all four of the same notes as F♯m7 - A C♯ E F♯. The lowest note of those doesn't necessarily make the name. If A *is* the lowest, the chord *could* be A6, root position, could be F♯m7 1st inversion. In your copy, F♯ happens to be the lowest note, so someone decided it must have that name. It could just as easily been named A6, in 3rd inversion.

Often publications of older songs have inexactitudes. Sometimes it's for simplicity, sometimes ignorance or simple mistakes.